# How to deal with memory leak in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks

I'm developping a Rails application that deals with huge amounts of
data and it halts since it uses all memory of my computer due to
memory leak (allocated objects that are not released).

In my application, data is organized in a hierarchical way, as a tree,
where each node of level "X" contains the sum of data of level
"X+1". For example if the data of level "X+1" contains the amount of
people in cities, level "X" contains the amount of people in
states. In this way, level "X"'s data is obtained by summing up the
amount of data in level "X+1" (in this case, people).

For the sake of this question, consider a tree with four levels:
country, State, City and Neighbourhoods and that each level is mapped
into Activerecords tables (countries, states, cities, neighbourhoods).

Data is read from a csv file that fills the leaves of the tree, that is,
the neighbourhoods table.

Afetr that, data flows from bottom (neighbourhoods) to top (countries) in the following sequence:

```
1) Neighbourhoods data is summed to Cities;
2) after step 1 is completed, Cities  data is summed to States;
3) after step 2 is completed, States  data is summed to Country;
```

The schematic code I'm using is as follows:

```
1 cities = City.all
2 cities.each do |city|
3   city.data = 0
4   city.neighbourhoods.each do |neighbourhood|
5       city.data = city.data + neighbourhood.data
6   end
7   city.save
8 end
```

The lowest level of the tree contains 3.8M of records. Each time lines
2-8 are executed, a city is summed up and after line 8 is executed,
that subtree is no longer needed, but it is never released (memory
leak). After summing 50% of the cities, all my 8Gbytes of RAM
vanishes.

My question is what can I do. Buy better hardware will not
do since I'm working with a "small" prototype.

I know a way to make it work: restart the application for each City,
but I hope someone has a better idea. The "simplest" would be to force
the garbage collector to free specific objects, but seems is not a way
to do it
(https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/how-do-i-force-ruby-to-release-memory/195515).

From the following articles I understood that the developer should
organize the data in a way to "suggest" the garbage collector what
should be freed. Maybe another approach will do the trick, but the only
alternative I see is Depth-first search approach instead of the
reversed Breadth-first search I'm using, but I don't see why it should work.

What I read so far:

https://stackify.com/how-does-ruby-garbage-collection-work-a-simple-tutorial/

https://www.toptal.com/ruby/hunting-ruby-memory-issues

https://scoutapm.com/blog/ruby-garbage-collection

https://scoutapm.com/blog/manage-ruby-memory-usage

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us an example of what `data` and `neighborhoods.data` actually is? Is it just a simple integer?

Comment: Yes, is an integer.

Comment: Sorry, but did not understand what "pushing the work into your database' means. Saving the records as in line 8?

Comment: It means that you're doing this in the most ineffective way possible - by pulling all the data out of the database at once ([instead of in batches](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html)) and then iterating across all the nested records to do a simple calculation that the database can do much more efficiently. If you provide an actual example of the DB schema we can probably give you an example of an update query which will run orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a case of a memory leak. You're just indescrimely loading data off the table which will exhaust the available memory.

The solution is to load the data off the database [in batches](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html):

```
City.find_each do |city|
  city.update(data: city.neighbourhoods.sum(&:data))
end
```

If `neighbourhoods.data` is a simple integer you don't need to fetch the records in the first place:

```
City.update_all(
  'data = (SELECT SUM(neighbourhoods.data) FROM neighbourhoods WHERE neighbourhoods.city_id = cities.id)'
)
```

This will be an order of magnitude faster and have a trivial memory consumption as all the work is done in the database.

If you REALLY want to load a bunch of records into rails then make sure to select aggregates instead of instantiating all those nested records:

```
City.left_joins(:neighbourhoods)
    .group(:id)
    .select(:id, 'SUM(neighbourhoods.data) AS n_data')
    .find_each { |c| city.update(data: n_data) }
```

Comment: I implemented you suggestions. Bellow I summarize the results for the
level X+1 of the tree summed up to the level X. (data is an integer,
X+1 has 3.8M records and the app that measures memory use starts at
32%): (1) my original approach: 1h32m to sum up 30% of level X+1's
data and freeze hitting 100% of memory (2) batches approach
(find_each) 0h37m to sum up 100% of level X+1's data and no more than
64% of memory use. (3) push the work to the database (City.update_all)
0h0m40 (40 seconds!) and the memory use line did not move. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your how your model associations are setup, should be able to take advantage of preloading.

For Example:

```rb
class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :neighborhoods

class Neighborhood < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :state

class State < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :neighborhoods

class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :states


cities = City.all.includes(neighborhoods: { state: :country })
cities.each do |city|
  ...
end
```

Comment: While this will avoid a N+1 query it won't really improve the memory consumption issue as you're still loading the entire table intro memory and all the associated items.

Comment: Perhaps not the best answer but still an answer/alternative. I wouldn't say this should be downvoted because it's not the most efficient solution. It is still _one_ answer to the proposed question.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but not all answers are useful answers - especially if they don't solve tie issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need rails at all, with pure SQL should be good enough to do what you're trying:

```
City.connection.execute(<<-SQL.squish)
  UPDATE cities SET cities.data = (
    SELECT SUM("neighbourhoods.data")
    FROM neighbourhoods
    WHERE neighbourhoods.city_id = cities.id
  ) 
  SQL
```